# 64 bit hex accepted for 128 bit identifier

Tags: spring-cloud-sleuth, opentracing

I am working on a sample test application with Spring cloud starter sleuth, 2.0.1.RELEASE.

I have the following property configured spring.sleuth.traceId128=true.

My expectation is that this ensures that 128 bit traces are always generated and if there is valid hex less < 128 bits, it is replaced by a new 128 bit value.

Here are some use cases I executed:

1. No x-b3-trace-id in header - generates a new 128 bit hex id.
2. A valid hex value less than 64 bit is adjusted to be 64 bits long. So '9bd0082a7ecfa' becomes '0009bd0082a7ecfa'
3. A valid 64 bit hex is never replaced. So, 'bc50f6e7eb5fa554' remains 'bc50f6e7eb5fa554'.

It seems like despite setting this property, anything <=64 is adjusted only upto 64 bits.

Is my understanding of this property incorrect. How do I ensure that only 128 bit values are allowed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please upgrade to a latest stable release version and see if the situation is the same?

Comment: Thanks @MarcinGrzejszczak. Tried with spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:2.1.5.RELEASE but the behavior is still the same.
x-b3-traceid:f321d0630190d4f1
x-b3-spanid:bbb
MDC values ->[f321d0630190d4f1] [000000000000bbbb]

Comment: Can you file an issue and create a small sample that replicates the problem please?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak - Done. Here is the link - https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1486